# How to calculate personal degree of confidence?

Tags: probability, logic

I have this multi-part question from Ian Hackling's book on probability and induction. I've split them into parts, with my answer and explanation below. Could someone check my answers though? I don't understand the topic and google yields wiki and the other SE answers are simpler.

> Wei thinks it is unlikely that there will be a major hailstorm in her
>   area over the next five years. She’s willing to pay you \$15 if there
>   is such a hailstorm, and \$5 if there isn’t.
>
> (a) What is Wei’s personal degree of confidence that there will not be
>   a major hailstorm in her area over the next five years?

Her degree of confidence seems to be 3/4, as in she is 75% sure there won't be a major hailstorm in the area over the next five years.

> Wei thinks it is fairly probable that her house will need a new roof
>   in the next five years, if there is a major hailstorm during that
>   time. Supposing there is a major hailstorm during that time, Wei’s
>   willing to pay you \$10 if her house needs a new roof, if you’ll pay
>   her \$10 if it doesn’t.
>
> (b) What is Wei’s personal (conditional) degree of confidence that her
>   house will need a new roof in the next five years, if there is a major
>   hailstorm during that time?

Seems simple enough, 50% is her degree of confidence.

> Wei also thinks it is really unlikely that her house will need a new
>   roof in the next five years, if there is not a major hailstorm during
>   that time. Supposing there is not a major hailstorm during that time,
>   Wei’s willing to pay you $1 if her house needs a new roof, if you’ll
>   pay her \$9 if it doesn’t.
>
> (c) What is Wei’s personal (conditional) degree of confidence that her
>   house will need a new roof in the next five years, if there is not a
>   major hailstorm during that time?

She seems to be 10% sure, is this right? What do they mean by conditional?

> (d) What is Wei’s personal degree of confidence that her house will
>   need a new roof in the next five years?

This, I assume, is combining the answers from above. If there is a storm -> 25% and 50% that it would need replacement. Along with 10% otherwise. Adding together, we get $0.25 * 0.5 + 0.1 = 0.225$.

Do my answers seem right? Any advice?

Comment: The question in (a) seems to be different to the others in that Wei pays for either event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is flawed:  Wei will pay me if there is a hailstorm, and **pay me** less if there is not.  If the question meant I would have to pay Wei if there was no strom, then yur answer is right.

Question (c) is well posed but almost certainly not what the questioner meant.  As written, Wei would need to be 90% sure of needing a new house if there is no hailstorm.

A conditional degree of confidence is the probability that event X will happen given that you know that event Y will happen.  You seem to have the concept right; you understood it for question (b).

Your technique for question (d) is a bit off; the 10% otherwise is 10% of the  chance there is on hailstorm, or 0.075.

Comment: I see what you mean about (a) and (c), I assume that they meant Wei pays $5 for example. I don't exactly get you how you got 0.075 for (d). Can I ask how you got there?